# Is there a way to complement missing numbers in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm quite new to R so please excuse me if what I'm asking is somewhat trivial.
So, I acquired a csv file containing something like this from an image analysis program:

```
FRAME      OBJECT_IS_IN_TARGET_AREA
1          0
2          1
5          1
6          0
7          0
...        ...
241        1
```

As you can see, there is no row for frame 3 and 4 and there might be rows missing further down until frame 241. Now, is there a way to complement the dataframe with the missing rows to receive a consecutive sequence of numbers ranging from 1 to 241 and assign each complemented row N/A for OBJECT_IS_IN_TARGET_AREA? The data frame should look like this in the end:

```
FRAME      OBJECT_IS_IN_TARGET_AREA
1          0
2          1
3          N/A
4          N/A
5          1
6          0
7          0
...        ...
241        1
```

Sadly, it is not possible to acquire these values from the image analysis program directly so I'd have to add them manually. Since I have **a lot** of these sequences this would be very tideous work. This is why I opted for R. Hope you can help me out.

Great Thanks,

E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `complete` from library `tidyr`. Assuming your data frame name is df,

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% complete(FRAME=c(1:241)) -> df
```

should do the intended work.

Comment: Get my upvote but I think `complete` is `tidyr`not `dplyr`, look at `?complete`.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I often times just load `tidyverse`, but I know for sure `complete` isn't from there. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Or `complete(FRAME = full_seq(FRAME, 1))` to avoid having to know the first and last values of `FRAME`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this using `baseR`:

```r
Frame <- seq(241)
df <- data.frame(Frame=Frame)
df$OBJECT_IS_IN_TARGET_AREA <- ifelse(df$Frame %in% yourCSV$Frame, yourCSV$OBJECT_IS_IN_TARGET_AREA, NA)
```

Now `df` will be your complemented data frame with `NA` for objects not in your `Frame` and values of `OBJECT_IS_IN_TARGET_AREA` for values in your csv  `Frame`.

A sample of `yourCSV` `dataframe`

```r
yourCSV <- data.frame(Frame=c(1,2,3,10,241), OBJECT_IS_IN_TARGET_AREA=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
df <- merge(data.frame(FRAME = c(1:nrow(df))), df, by = "FRAME", all.x = TRUE)
```